# Verificar se checkbox esta selecionado no input

Tags: html, jquery

Gostaria de disparar um evento javascript direto no input do tipo checkbox quando este estiver selecionado. Por exemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" isSelected="call()">
```

Obs.: Não quero fazer um script.

Comment: Como você quer disparar um evento sem usar um script? Só há evento na página com script.

Comment: Eu quero chamar uma função em javascript se o box estiver selecionado, mas quero fazer isso no input (como expliquei ali), não quero fazer $('.namebox').is(":checked")... em uma função a parte. Entendeu?

Comment: Não resolveria `<input  onchange="if (this.checked) call() " ...`  ?

Comment: O problema é que o box já vem selecionado...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `onchange` e fazer um `if` que caso o campo estiver "checado", irá disparar a função.

Adicionei a mesma função, só que no `onload` da página, para fazer a chamada da função quando o documento for carregado.

```js
function check() {     
     console.log('oi');
}
```

```html
<body onload=" if(ipt1.checked) check()">
<input id="ipt1" type="checkbox" checked onload="check()" onchange="if(this.checked) check()">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: O problema é que o box já vem selecionado...

Comment: se ele já vem selecionado, você pode chamar a função no `onload` do seu `body`, já que a função será disparada de qualquer forma ao iniciar a página, certo? Ai você mantém o `onchage` que irá verificar caso o usuário altere.

Comment: Editei a resposta, dê uma olhada no exemplo.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus só troca o `alert()` por um `console.log()`, é menos intrusivo pra quem vai verificar a resposta ou ver o resultado e tem a mesma efetividade.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer chamar um evento JavaScript direto no `input` no carregamento da página caso o `checkbox` esteja marcado.

Alguns eventos podem ser disparados no carregamento da página sem o uso de um script normal (entre as tags `<script></script>` ou de um `.js` externo). Só que não é o caso de um `input`. Um elemento do tipo `input` só suporta alguns eventos com a interação do usuário (ex., `onclick`, `onchange`, `onmouseover` etc.).

Em vista dessa limitação, sua intenção em chamar um evento desta forma direto no `input` não é possível, porque ele não suporta nenhum tipo de evento que detecta o carregamento da página.

A única forma seria um evento `onload` no `body` ou até em uma imagem qualquer, que suporta `onload`:

### Body

```js
function call(){
   console.log("Checado!");
}
```

```html
<body onload="if(document.body.querySelector('input[name=box]').checked) call();">
<input name="box" type="checkbox" checked />
```

### Imagem

```html
<script>
function call(){
   console.log("Checado!");
}
</script>
<img height="50" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" onload="if(document.body.querySelector('input[name=box]').checked) call();" />
<input name="box" type="checkbox" checked />
```